# Merge two or more rules in different files in Less

Tags: less

I'm relatively new to Less (and precompilers).

I have three files, defined as this:

```css
//global.less
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
//...


//global-flex.less
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
main {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
//...
```

And a third file (main.less) where I import both of those files.

```css
@import "global.less";
@import "global-flex.less";
//Other imports and files also happens, but they are not relevant to this question.
```

When i compile main.less, my output is:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
main {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

I want the output to "merge" the two matching "body" rules, like this:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
main {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't think it's possible.

Comment: You can write mixins `.some-name() {margin: 0; padding: 0;}` in imported files and call them in less file with imports: `body { .some-name() ; }`. But it doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: @3rdthemagical Exactly, originally, I thought to use mixins, but, in my use case, there files are generally unknown to each other (i.e.: site library). I need something that "blends" multiple distinct LESS files and merges those selectors at output.

Comment: If you are using grunt, gulp or webpack you can minify output code. And result would be as you expect. For example https://csscompressor.com/